# Is there a word for motion that a bull makes when it kicks back with his legs before charging?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for motion that a bull makes when it kicks back with his legs before charging?

Kind of like at 22s in the following video

http://youtu.be/pjM_67aOT3Y?t=22s

Even if it's not an English word!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The entry for [paw in the AHDL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pawing) includes:

> **2.** To strike or scrape with a beating motion: *The bull pawed the ground before charging.*

From an article on a UCB site by a professor of veterinary medicine titled, [Why and how to read a cow or bull](http://nature.berkeley.edu/ucce50/ag-labor/7article/article29.htm):

> The direct threat is head-on with head lowered and shoulders hunched and neck curved to the side toward the potential object of the aggression (Photo 2). **Pawing with the forefeet**, sending dirt flying behind or over the back, as well as rubbing or horning the ground are often **components of the threat display** (Photo 3).

Comment: "To Paw" has so many other meanings than just this specific act. It's not quite the answer I was looking for but maybe there just isn't a word for this type of pawing.

Comment: @sgryzko As far as I know there is no other word in English, however the phrase "pawing the ground" in the first part of this answer is very specific and only really relates to agitated animals.

Answer (score -1):

Defasio.

I couldn't find the answer to the same question. I settled on Defasio, which looks like it might be a Portuguese word? I agree with the OP "pawing" doesn't seem adequate for this action.

Comment: Is this a real word though? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean "desafio" meaning "challenge" in both Portuguese and Spanish? This came up when I googled "defasio".

Comment: "Defasio" doesn't exist in portuguese :) but "Desafio", yes, which means "challenge". I am not sure is the answer for this particular point of the bull but just wanted to clarify this :)